# How to determine the navigate data from Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, service

I can get data like this:

```
    final Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("content");
..
final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot =
                  snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>;
..
image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                  querySnapshot.docs[index].data()['image'],
..
```

In this way, I can add new content with the data I entered from Firestore. I wrote lines of code for when these contents are clicked the pages to go to:

```
case 'camp':
        {
          //statements;
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (redContext) => const CampLoadingScreen()));
          popUpFunc();
        }
        break;
```

So when I add new content to Firestore, the pages to go to cannot be found because I need to add to lines of code. I probably need to create a service.dart file and write the necessary information in it. But i don't know how to do that. Can you help me for that?